# Is there an OpenWRT feature for tracking internet data usage per user?

Tags: openwrt

Is there an OpenWRT feature or package I can install that would allow me to track internet data usage per user? I'm thinking of a system that requires all devices to login with a username and password so their internet data usage can be tracked regardless of device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at this: [wrtbwmon](https://github.com/pyrovski/wrtbwmon).

> A small shell script designed to run on linux powered routers
> (OpenWRT, DD-WRT, Tomato, and other routers where shell access is
> available). It provides per user bandwidth monitoring capabilities and
> generates usage reports.

You might need only that, but i haven't tried it yet.
I got the reference from here: [Bandwidth Monitoring](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/bwmon).

Comment: https://github.com/pyrovski/wrtbwmon is an updated version for (at least) OpenWRT

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a "port mirroring" package to forward network packets to another computer.

So you can setup an internet monitoring program to record internet activities.

http://code.google.com/p/port-mirroring/

Comment: Does not answer the question. Asker wants to have it on the router.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Coova Chilli](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli)

It is easy to install and has a lot of features. You can authenticate by mac address or by username and password and you can also create rules to limit peoples bandwidth or give them a daily allowance.

It create a web based captive portal for your users when they try to connect to the internet. Warnign: You will need to be comfortable with editing the settings on the command line for this to work well, but there are lots of tutorials out there.